# Проблема с программой для парсинга сайта на хостинге (Python)

Tags: python, парсер, requests, hosting

У меня есть программа для парсинга на python и она отлично работает у меня на ПК, но на хостинге PythonAnyWhere она выдаёт ошибку. Подскажите в чём проблема.

```
import requests
import random
# -*- coding: utf8 -*
    
    
URL = 'https://av.by/' 
print('1')
responce = requests.post(URL)
print('2')

if responce.status_code == 200:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('not ok')
    print(responce.status_code)
```

И такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 805, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 308, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 898, in _tunnel
    raise OSError("Tunnel connection failed: %d %s" % (code,
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 637, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='av.by', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Egorka228/Bot/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    responce = requests.post(URL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='av.by', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden
')))
```

Comment: а зачем вы используете `POST` и не передаёте данные? Ну и судя по коду 403 вам отказано в доступе)

Comment: И как это исправить?

Comment: сменить `post` на `get`

Comment: Это решение не помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests import Session
  
URL = 'https://av.by/'
with Session() as s:
    response = s.get(URL)
    print('2')

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('ok')
    else:
        print('not ok')
        print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: На ПК работает, но на PythonAnyWhere нет. Но спасибо за вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решило смена хостинга pythonanywhere на хероку. Хороший и удобный хостинг.